# Using retina.js script. Non-retina images do not display at all

Tags: retina.js

I'm trying to use the retina.js script. If I understand correctly, when there is no @2x version of an image, the regular image is supposed to display. This is not what is happening for me, though. The regular version displays for a second and then disappears.The images that I do have @2x versions of *are* properly replaced, however.

It's like the script looks for a @2x version, if doesn't find it, it displays nothing.
Is this the way it is supposed to work?? Is there something within the script I need to change? I don't want or necessarily need to have @2x versions of all my graphics.

I'm testing on an iPad3 and iPhone4S

Comment: did you find an answer to this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: try to update the retina.js script to the latest version...